# Where do i edit <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

Tags: magento-1.9, page-content

Can someone tell me the path to edit the content in

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

Comment: which content your are going to edit??if it is CMS pages content you can do it from admin side only please be more specific.

Comment: its for the home page my home page is taking time to load so I was thinking to comment
echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')
echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages')
 echo $this->getChildHtml('before_footer')
 echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end')

Answer (score 3):

`getChildHtml()` method is a special function which will used to show html content of a child block inside a parent block. The method is defined inside the class `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` which is located at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php`.

Basically we can pass three parameters to this method. In which first one is important. The first parameter is name of a child block. In this case `content` is a child block name.

`content` block is `core/text_list` type block. This block is actually used to hold all other blocks that should come inside the content section of a page. There are other similar block does exist in Magento. Some of them are `left`, `right` blocks etc. As their name indicates they holds blocks which will come under in specific place of a page. Hence we can call this blocks as `structural blocks` since they actually responsible for making structure of a page.

There is only one parent block that holds these structural blocks. It is `root` block. Root block is also can be treat as a `page layout container block` which just act as a container block of magento page layout.

All of this definitions comes inside `page.xml` file.

However in general it is very difficult find which block stands for

```
 getChildHtml('some.name');
```

In order to find `some.name` block, first we need to find the template that holds this method stands for which block. Then you should find which layout xml file defines that parent block. Then you can see a child block with name `some.name` inside that block there. However it is not 100% sure. The inclusion of a child block can happen anywhere.